# Adding values to an array inside hash in vue not working

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I am trying add the feature to add multiple workers when clicked on Add worker. The issue I am facing here is that when I put workers array inside the management then this feature doesn't work. But if puts workers array outside the management hash then it works. But I want it to be inside the management issue. I am getting the error **cannot read the property push**.

```
<div v-for="(worker, index) in management.workers" :key="index">
  <v-container fluid>
    <v-layout row wrap>
      <v-flex xs12 md6 class="add-col-padding-right info-align">
        <v-text-field
           label='Name'
           v-model="worker.name"
           >
        </v-text-field>
      </v-flex>
      <v-flex xs12 md6 class="add-col-padding-left info-align">
        <v-text-field
           label='Hours of work'
           v-model="worker.hours_of_work"
           >
        </v-text-field>
      </v-flex>
   </v-layout>
   <v-btn class="red-button next-btn" @click="deleteRow(index)">Delete</v-btn>
 </v-container>                 
</div> 
<v-btn class="red-button next-btn" @click="addRow">Add Workers</v-btn>


<script>

export default {
  data () {
    return {
      management: {
        workers: []
      }
    }
  }
 methods: {
    addRow() {

      this.management.workers.push({
        name: '',
        hours_of_work: '',
        total: ''
      })
    },
    deleteRow(index) {
      this.management.workers.splice(index,1)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code seems to work below:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data() {
    return {
      management: {
        workers: []
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    addRow() {
      this.management.workers.push({
        name: '',
        hours_of_work: '',
        total: ''
      })
    },
    deleteRow(index) {
      this.management.workers.splice(index, 1)
    },
    getRows(){
      console.clear()
      console.log(this.management.workers)
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@4.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.2.20/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/babel-polyfill/dist/polyfill.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.2.20/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <div v-for="(worker, index) in management.workers" :key="index">
      <v-container fluid>
        <v-layout row wrap>
          <v-flex xs12 md6 class="add-col-padding-right info-align">
            <v-text-field label='Name' v-model="worker.name">
            </v-text-field>
          </v-flex>
          <v-flex xs12 md6 class="add-col-padding-left info-align">
            <v-text-field label='Hours of work' v-model="worker.hours_of_work">
            </v-text-field>
          </v-flex>
        </v-layout>
        <v-btn class="red-button next-btn" @click="deleteRow(index)">Delete</v-btn>
      </v-container>
    </div>
    <v-btn class="red-button next-btn" @click="addRow">Add Workers</v-btn>
    <v-btn class="red-button next-btn" @click="getRows">View Workers</v-btn>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Comment: Only thing I see wrong is a missing comma between `data` and `methods` object

Comment: yes i tried that. but it doesn't work work me. I am getting cannot read the push property error.

Comment: Can you create a running example on stackblitz or a code snippet here itself that demonstrates the issue? Otherwise nobody can keep guessing the possibilities unless we see the issue ourself

Comment: @user12763413 Is your issue resolved then? What was the problem?

Comment: I have strings being passed to the database but I had workers assigned as an array. That was causing the problem.